# ユーザーアクティビティの回答や信用度などのタブのツールチップの文字列が未翻訳

Tags: バグ, 翻訳

### 不具合事象

ユーザーアクティビティの中央にあるユーザーが行った回答、質問や信用度を閲覧出来るタブのツールチップに設定されている文字列が未翻訳になっています。以下の画像は[コミュニティ♦ユーザーのアクティビティ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/%E3%82%B3%E3%83%9F%E3%83%A5%E3%83%8B%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3?tab=topactivity)でのスクリーンショットです。

また、これらのツールチップの文字列は ja.traducir.win 上に存在しないようです。

- [「Badges this user has earned」の検索結果](https://ja.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=Badges%20this%20user%20has%20earned)

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

### 関連投稿

Meta Stack Exchange にて同様の投稿がありました。当該投稿によれば、ページングのリンクにおいても同じ問題が発生しているようです。

- [Add tooltip strings from the profile activity page into transifex (or use existing keys) - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345101)

Comment: MSE でも既に同様の要望が挙がっています。 - https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345101/403540

Answer (score 3, accepted):

質問文に記載した[関連投稿](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/345370)より、 ja.traducir.win に当該文字列が追加されたことを確認しました。

- https://ja.traducir.win/strings/13271